# How to sum (aggregate) all the values in a key/value JSONB?

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-10

in Postgres 10 I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
    id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
    qty jsonb
);
INSERT INTO testtable (id,qty)
VALUES
  ( 1, '{"2018-08-01": 10, "2018-08-11": 20, "2018-10-23": 30}' ),
  ( 2, '{"2018-08-17": 100, "2018-11-01": 200}' ),
  ( 3, '{"2018-09-03": 1, "2018-09-01": 2, "2018-10-01": 3}' );
```

Is there a quick way, using SQL to return the sum of each JSONB field so that the results would be:

```
ID Total
1   60
2   300
3   6
```

I have seen more complicated possibilities using UNNEST and/or replace (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699601/sum-of-values-of-json-array-in-postgresql).

However, I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Are these numbers inside the jsonb floats -- do they have a fractional part? Or, are they just integers?

Comment: More a theoretical question. Most likely will be Integer so can cast to Integer.

Answer (score 5):

Despite having searched for hours I think I found my answer 10 minutes after posting!

Including for reference for others:

```
SELECT id, sum(value::float)
FROM testtable
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(qty)
GROUP BY id;
```